# Best practice for multi country magento store setup

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, best-practice

this is my first magento build and just had some questions on the best method to set the store up.

It's a single business but running out of 2 countries. These are the specifics:

- Products to be shared between to two sites - but stock levels and pricing to be different
- Tax to be different
- Shipping to be different
- Static page content (home, about etc..) to be different.

I'd like to run it as mydomain.com/us/ and mydomain.com/aus/ for the two countries

If anyone would have any advices on if this is doable and a good way to go about it, that would be awesome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to create two websites (not stores) on your single Magento instance to keep the product catalog shared between them. This also allows you have different prices/currency, taxes, shipping methods, static pages, etc. You can have the different domains as well.

What you won't get from default Magento is separate inventory pools. Unfortunately, Magento supports only global inventory. There are extensions, though. I've used one from AITOC. It worked OK..

Comment: Thats perfect, thanks very much for that, I will look into this further :)